How to install multiple mediawiki wikis with short URLs on Rocky Linux with nginx?
I have a Rocky Linux server using nginx/php-fpm, and I would like to run multiple Mediawiki wikis for multiple sites, with the following configuration:
Installation

Running in a subdirectory that is NOT the website root (location = /)

e.g. a wiki-specific block
location ~ ^/wiki 
{
    ...
}


I believe this to be the primary impediment, as almost all example configurations use rewrite rules and other structures than cannot be nested within a location block.



Using short URLs (URL rewrites)

e.g. https://example1.org/w/index.php?title=Page_title --> https://example1.org/wiki/Page_title
see also: Manual:Short URL/Nginx


Using php-fpm socket


Additional wikis

As stated above, multiple wikis for separate domains will be hosted (call them example1.org, example2.org, example3.org).

I was going to use this guide, but one must first complete the primary installation before adding other wikis.



Latest attempt
/etc/nginx/sites_available/example1.org.conf
# Redirect from www to non-www bare domain
server
{
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/fullchain.pem;   # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/privkey.pem;     # managed by Certbot

    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     ~^(www\.)(?<subdomain>.*)example1.org$;

    return          301 https://${subdomain}example1.org$request_uri;
}

# autoconfig.example1.org
server { ... }

# example1.org
server 
{
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/fullchain.pem;   # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/privkey.pem;     # managed by Certbot

    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     example1.org;
    root            /srv/static/example1.org/www;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example1.org/access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example1.org/error.log;

    location = /
    {
        index       index.html;
    }
    
    location /wiki 
    {
        alias       /srv/mediawiki-1.42.1/;
        index       index.php;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location /wiki/\.php$
        {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/mediawiki-1.42.1$fastcgi_script_name;            
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        # Additional configuration for static files and security
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ 
        {
            try_files $uri /wiki/index.php?$query_string;
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~* ^/wiki/images/ 
        {
            try_files $uri /wiki/index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~* ^/wiki/(cache|includes|maintenance|languages|serialized|tests|images/deleted)/ 
        {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^/wiki/(bin|docs|extensions|includes|maintenance|mw-config|resources|serialized|tests)/ 
        {
            internal;
        }
    }
}

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user                nginx;
worker_processes    auto;
error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                 /run/nginx.pid;

# Optimize by precompiling regular expressions on startup
pcre_jit        on;

events
{
    worker_connections   1024;
}

http
{
    include     mime.types;
    include     /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/*.conf;
    include     /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    # Compression - requires gzip and gzip static modules.
    gzip        on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_vary   on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 700;

    # Compression levels over 6 do not give an appreciable improvement
    # in compression ratio, but take more resources.
    gzip_comp_level 6;

    # IE 6 and lower do not support gzip with Vary correctly.
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    # Before nginx 0.7.63:
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    server_names_hash_bucket_size   256;
    server_names_hash_max_size      1024;

    # Redirect http traffic to https
    server
    {
        listen      80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        return      301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # Catch-all server for requests to invalid hosts.
    # Also catches vulnerability scanners probing IP addresses.
    server
    {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name bogus;
        root        /var/empty;
        
        return      444;

        location /
        {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }

    # If running php as fastcgi, specify php upstream.
    upstream php
    {
        server      unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm.socket;
    }
}

Currently, with the above configuration I get index.php loaded as a text file.  With the text:
// If you are reading this in your web browser, your server is probably
// not configured correctly to run PHP applications!

I have found countless examples of how to do each of the desired attributes listed above, but none with all of them together; changes for one solution invariably break the other(s).
Any help would be extremely appreciated!
